# How to count 2 columns with a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

```
A         B        C

Val 1     2  
Val 2     1  
Val 3     1  

Item 1    Val 1    1  
Item 2    Val 2    1  
Item 3    Val 3    0  
Item 4    Val 1    0
```

Consider the above sheet. In the first 3 rows I am counting how many times corresponding val# shows up in the sheet. I have done that with: `=COUNTIF($B$5:$B, A1)` However, I can't figure out how to make it count only if the value matches and column C doesn't have a 1 next to it on same row. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

try `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(B$5:B, A1, C$5:C, "<>"&1)
```

[image: 0]

---

make sure **C** column is formatted as **Number**

Comment: The `"<>"&1` did not work for me but when I tried `"="&0` then it works and I can live with it saying 0 for things that should not count

Comment: @Bojan yeah, that would work too... https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNeE6.png